# Multiple dependencies between columns in HANA SQL

Tags: sql, hana

I have a question regarding SQL best practices in the following case.
I have a select SQL query (within SQL script calculation view) which calculates some columns on the fly.
It looks like (I provided a simplified code just to show the problem):

```
SELECT  ... ,
        "COL1" ,
        "COL2" * "COL3" AS "COL4" ,
        CASE WHEN "COL4" > "COL1" THEN sth
             ELSE sth2
        END AS "COL5" ,
        CASE WHEN "COL5" > sthelse THEN sthelse2
             ELSE sthelse3
        END AS "COL6"
FROM    ...
```

The above code doesn't work because of the error "invalid column name". I know that it's impossible to use the column produced by a case statement in the other case expression. I have several dependencies like that and don't want to have a deeply nested query like:

```
SELECT  ...
FROM    ( SELECT    * ,
                    CASE WHEN "COL5" > sthelse THEN sthelse2
                         ELSE sthelse3
                    END AS "COL6"
          FROM      ( SELECT    * ,
                                CASE WHEN "COL4" > "COL1" THEN sth
                                     ELSE sth2
                                END AS "COL5"
                      FROM      (...
```

Is there any way of resolving this without multi-level nested queries in SAP HANA? I would appreciate any advices. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One option here could be to use decision tables in SAP HANA. 
Alternatively, you may consider building a graphical calculation view with the respective calculations in a projection node.
In "pure" SQL there's not too much you can do, except for nesting the column definitions.